# Making REST calls to RavenDB Studio Version 3.5.3

Tags: rest, soapui, ravendb

I am trying to make REST GET call on RavenDB studio (the latest stable release) running on localhost using SOAP UI with following parameters :

```
GET /databases/Northwind/indexes/
dynamic/Products?query=Category:categories/2&explain=true
```

The call should return a result from server.
However, I am getting empty JSON content. Could someone please let me know the correct resource name and parameter list to accomplish the same . TIA

Edit: After correcting the request parameter as query = Category:categories/2 I got the following response :

```
[
  {
  "Index": "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
  "Reason": "Query is specific for entity name, but the index searches across all of them, may result in a different type being returned."
  },
  {
  "Index": "Orders/ByCompany",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Orders/Totals",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Product/Sales",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Users/ByName",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Auto/Orders/ByCompanyAndShipTo_Country",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Auto/Orders/ByLines_Product",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
  },
  {
  "Index": "Auto/Orders/ByCompanyAndLines_ProductAndLines_QuantitySortByLines      _Quantity",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
   },
  {
  "Index": "Auto/Orders/ByCompanyAndOrderedAtAndShipTo_CountrySortByOrderedAt       ",
  "Reason": "Index does not apply to entity name: Products"
```

There is a dynamic index on RavenDB server by the name Auto/Products/ByCategoryAndDiscontinuedAndNameAndSupplierSortByDiscontinued. But it is not showing up on the response.It should apply to the query.

---

Comment: Shuba Lakshmi, please check if the service /endpoint is running. By the way, was it a public service?

Comment: I did check, it is up and running. And it does not use any authentication/ credentials.

Comment: Were you able to invoke the service successfully with `POSTMAN`? Are you expecting only `json` response? Have you checked `xml` tab of the response to see if there is anything?

Comment: I did not try POSTMAN, only SoapUI RESTproject and the response does not return any xml.

Comment: check the status code, it might be permission issue

Comment: The status code is Http/1/1 200 OK , only the JSON content which is coming from the server is empty.  {empty-JSON-content}

Comment: Although I am able to access documents by their ID using URI http://localhost:8080/databases/northwind/docs/orders/1 etc. I just wanted to try the URI mentioned in Inside RavenDB 3.0 book for getting explanation for using a particular index by Raven DB.

Comment: It does not seem to be permission issue either as in config file AnonymousAccess is set to admin.

Comment: Post the full content of the response here.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Raven-Server-Build: 35191
Temp-Request-Time: 0
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 05:24:58 GMT

Comment: Hi, I got the correct content! The mistake I was making was sending incorrect parameter to server, where I was sending Category = categories/2 before , it should have been query = Category:categories/2.

Comment: The strange thing I noticed in response is absence of index (dynamic index generated by RavenDB Auto/Products/ByCategoryAndDiscontinuedAndNameAndSupplierSortByDiscontinued). Rest of the indices do not apply to the query.

Comment: @ShubhaLakshmi If you figured out the answer by yourself, you should post the full solution as an answer here, then accept it (once you get enough rep) so others can more easily find (and therefore benefit) from your work. Thanks.